# Why can't I detect when an AuiNotebook page is closed?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm binding the `EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGE` event to the `AuiNotebook` successfully, but `EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSE` and `EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSED` both do nothing. The bound handler is never run. My construction and binding code looks like this:

```
self.notebook = wx.aui.AuiNotebook(self)
self.Bind(wx.aui.EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSE, self.on_page_close)
self.Bind(wx.aui.EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED, self.on_page_changed)
```

And my event handler simply looks like this:

```
def on_page_close(self, event):
    print 'Page closed', event
```

Why don't the page close events do anything?

---

*Just in case, [here is the full source file](http://pastebin.com/iswgYEfM) with the relevant lines highlighted.*

Comment: Should you not be using self.notebook.Bind?

Comment: @timc: Events propagate up, so it's not important where I `Bind` them.

Answer (score 1):

The close events are not triggered when pages are removed using `DeletePage` or `RemovePage`, only when they are closed using the little close buttons. There are no methods for programmatically closing a page that will trigger the page close events, so what ever on-close routines you want to perform, you have to put them in a separate function and call them both from the close event handler and from all the functions that invoke `RemovePage` or `DeletePage`.